# IF function, conditional multiplication

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have an issue with excel formula

```
=IF(L2="Y","I2*17-M2","N/A")
```

This works perfectly fine whenever L2 is not a 'Y' but when L2 is 'Y'it doesn't give the calculation of **I2*17-M2**. It just reproduces **I2*17-M2**.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes

```
=IF(L2="Y",I2*17-M2,"N/A")
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this or any other answer so the question will not remain unanswered